# SQL count on multiple columns including 0 value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've joined up my tables such that every entry is unique and I want to get a COUNT() value for how many unique courses the teachers teach. I figured I would make a table of distinct courses then do a count based on the teacher's id, however this doesn't account for teachers who taught no courses and I wish to return a zero value in this case. How do I go about getting these zero values?

Table for reference:

```
  id   |    name    | course_id | sec_id | semester | year
-------+------------+-----------+--------+----------+------
 33456 | A          |           |        |          |
 10101 | B          | CS-101    | 1      | Fall     | 2009
 76766 | C          | BIO-301   | 1      | Summer   | 2010
 12121 | D          | FIN-201   | 1      | Spring   | 2010
 10101 | B          | CS-347    | 1      | Fall     | 2009
 76543 | E          |           |        |          |
 83821 | F          | CS-319    | 2      | Spring   | 2010
 83821 | F          | CS-190    | 2      | Spring   | 2009
 98345 | G          | EE-181    | 1      | Spring   | 2009
 10101 | B          | CS-315    | 1      | Spring   | 2010
 22222 | H          | PHY-101   | 1      | Fall     | 2009
 45565 | I          | CS-101    | 1      | Spring   | 2010
 15151 | J          | MU-199    | 1      | Spring   | 2010
 32343 | K          | HIS-351   | 1      | Spring   | 2010
 83821 | F          | CS-190    | 1      | Spring   | 2009
 45565 | I          | CS-319    | 1      | Spring   | 2010
 76766 | C          | BIO-101   | 1      | Summer   | 2009
 58583 | L          |           |        |          |
```

ps. I believe I am using PostgreSQL.

[EDIT] the expected result is a table of id's, names, and a number showing the amount of courses the teacher has taught, including 0 if they have not taught any course.

[EDIT 2] I only need a query on **this** table, all the other work is done. If there is no value for course_id, sec_id, semester, year then that teacher has **not** taught a course (in the case of teachers A, E, and L; who would have a count of 0). I only need a way to count these courses, nothing else.

Comment: if you want to modify your query - show it

Comment: any query can be made from this table, I have no further query, that is the issue.

Comment: what's the expected result then?..

Comment: apologies I thought I explained it well enough, edit added for expected result

Comment: You need to provide list of teachers (either from table or list of values) and LEFT JOIN table with courses (from your question).

Comment: These are all the teachers, and any course they have taught in the database. I only need to get a count for how many courses they teach from *this* table, including 0 if they teach no courses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's assume the table name is t:

```
select distinct count(course_id) filter (where course_id is not null) over (partition by id,name),id, name 
from t 
order by name;
 count |  id   |     name
-------+-------+--------------
     0 | 33456 |  A
     3 | 10101 |  B
     2 | 76766 |  C
     1 | 12121 |  D
     0 | 76543 |  E
     3 | 83821 |  F
     1 | 98345 |  G
     1 | 22222 |  H
     2 | 45565 |  I
     1 | 15151 |  J
     1 | 32343 |  K
     0 | 58583 |  L
(12 rows)
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html

Comment: I think you could also get the same result if you would do `GROUP BY id, name` and `SUM(CASE WHEN course_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`, no need for window or distinct then. I'm not sure what is faster.

Comment: Can confirm exact same result, any way for me to check how long these operations take?

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński I prefered window function here with filter as more readable. I assume speed would be comparable for both

Answer (score 0):

I believe, this query should do the job:

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT course_id), t.id, name FROM courses r Right Outer JOIN teachers t ON (r.id=t.id) group by t.id, name;

I assumed, that not all teachers where in the table you have provided, thus the need for the Outer Join. Tested on similar database on Oracle.

Comment: check my second edit, I only need a query on this table.

Answer (score 0):

Do the `join`s with `subquery`  to find the teachers course count

```
select t.name, coalesce(c.course_count, 0) course_count     
from table t left join (
     select name, count(distinct course _id) course_count 
     from table 
     group by name    
) c on c. name = t.name
group by t.name
```